# Laravel - How to keep checkboxes to stay checked or not after redirect in Laravel?

Tags: forms, laravel, checkbox

I am currently creating a form with 10 checkboxes in the form, once user click on submit, the form data will be posted to server, if fails it will be redirected back to the form page. At the moment after redirect, the checked checkboxes are cleared - default. I just wonder how would make the form remember the checked boxes and check them after redirect?

The Laravel version I use at the moment is 5.

Sorry if I am not so clear, please see the following -

1. The page will shows 10 categories (checkboxes) at the begining
2. user made selection, and hits submit button
3. If user logged in, votes will be sent to the server and store in the db
4. if not logged in, user select to register with fb
5. redirect back - and checkboxes unchecked.. (In here I want the checkboxes to remember the checked boxes and check them)

Any help would be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Michael

This is my view

#### SELECT 5 CATEGORIES

```
    <div>

        <form method="POST"  class='ajax' >

            <input type="hidden" name="_token" class="category-vote" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <ol>
                <!-- loop through each id from the database -->
                @foreach ($categories as $category)

                    <li> 
                        <!-- Get category names from the translation file by using category ids from db -->
                        <h4><?=trans('categories.category_' . $category->id . '_name')?></h4> 

                        <!-- Check if user has voted, if so - check the box -->
                        @if( in_array( $category->id, $catVotes ) )
                            <!-- Input checkbox for user to vote the category -->
                            <input type="checkbox" class='category-vote' name=<?=trans('categories.category_' . $category->id . '_input_name')?> checked> <br>
                        @else
                            <!-- Input checkbox for user to vote the category -->
                            <input type="checkbox" class='category-vote' name=<?=trans('categories.category_' . $category->id . '_input_name')?>> <br>
                        @endif

                        <!-- Get category image from the translation file by using cat ids from db -->
                        <img style='max-width: 300px;' src= <?=trans('categories.category_' . $category->id . '_img_path')?>>

                    </li>

                    <br/><br/>

                @endforeach

                <!-- Submit vote button -->
                @if ( Auth::check() )

                    <button id='submit-form' class="btn btn-primary">Submit your Votes!</button>

                @else

                    <button class="submit-btn btn btn-primary">Submit your Votes!</button>

                @endif  

            </ol>   

        </form>

    </div>
```

And this is my controller

```
         // Get Category
        $categories = Category::all();

        // Check if user has already voted categories
        $catVotes = [];

        // Check user is logged in and get users voted categoeis if voted
        if ( Auth::check() ){
            for( $i = 0; $i < count($categoryVotes); $i++ ){
                $catVotes[$i] = $categoryVotes[$i]->category_id;
            }
        }

        // Phase 1
        return view('vote-in-the-awards', compact('categories', 'catVotes'));
```

Comment: show us related code (controller and view)

Comment: I have updated with some related controller and view code. Thanks:)

Comment: You can only remember selected checkboxes from `one redirect`, other than that you need to use `sessions`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found a solution for this:

The only way to remember selected checkboxes after redirect is use AJAX and Session. So every time user check a checkbox, it fires an ajax call to the server with checkbox id, and in server side, store the in Session. And every time return to the view, check if Session contains checked boxes ids, if it has, check the boxes in front end.

Thats it!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should really only need to look at the input and see if the input is there.  For a checkbox, if it isn't selected it isn't sent to the server.

With that in mind, something like this should work...

```
<input type="checkbox" class='category-vote' name=<?=trans('categories.category_' . $category->id . '_input_name')?> {{ Input::has(trans('categories.category_' . $category->id . '_input_name')) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

It will just check to see if the input has a certain value and if it does, echo the word 'checked' which should hopefully check the checkbox.

Comment: The selected category has not been added to the Input, so its never returning anything related to the selected Categories.

Comment: How are your users getting redirected back to the form?

Comment: The user needs to be registered before they can submit their selection, so they click on Register with Facebook, the page redirects to Facebook and than redirect back to the form page.. done by using Sociallite.

Comment: When they get back to your app, are they logged in or do you have a user id?